# Delphi 7 convert XLS(X) to CSV

Tags: delphi, excel, csv, xls

I need something to convert XLS or XLSX files to csv(semi-colon separated). It could be a component, a dll or a command line tool but it must be unattended, not visible to the user and preferably have native support so no need for Excel to be installed.

Comment: Please take time when posting your question and use the preview window that appears below the text you're typing to check things like text and code formatting. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of good suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465154/reading-excel-spreadsheets-with-delphi). It seems not many of these support XLSX though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "unattended", but I think I would try to access and read the Excel files using ADO (dbGo) in Delphi. A comprehensive how-to article is available at [About.com Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa090903a.htm). Once the Excel data is in a TADOTable, it should be fairly easy to rewrite the table data into the desired CSV format and save it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ADO method supports reading and writing to XLS, XLSX, and XLSB files.

However, the 2010 version of the Microsoft Access Database Engine must be installed. The redistributable is free, and it doesn't require installation of Excel or Microsoft Office.

I verified last night that it works with all three Excel file formats.

Answer (score -1):

SMImport from [Scalabium](http://www.scalabium.com) supports XLS and XLSX natively. It's reasonably priced with good support. We have used it with great success.